# Python Newbie - Why does self._ causing a NameError in Python 3

Tags: python, class, self

I am attempting to learn how to use classes in Python and have managed to get the following code working through trial and error but am not sure how! It seems the use of 'self.' is sometimes required whilst at other times its use creates an error. I would be be very grateful of someone could explain why the different lines of code *seem* to behave so differently

If I replace the line `self._tot += _new` with `self._tot += self._new` then I get the following error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

Conversely, if I replace the line `self._tot -= self._last` with `self._tot -= _last` then I get the following error `NameError: name '_last' is not defined`

The code behaving in this seemingly contrary way is:-

```
class PremiumCounter:   

    def __init__(self, _tot = 0):
        self._tot = _tot        
        self._new = 0
        #self._last = 0

    def add(self, _new = 1):
        self._tot += _new
        self._last = _new

    def undo(self):
        self._tot -= self._last       

    def get_total(self):
        return self._tot

    def clear_counter(self):
        self._tot = 0



ConcertAttendee2 = PremiumCounter(4)#Creates ConcertAttendee2 as an instance of the 'ImprovedCounter' class


ConcertAttendee2.clear_counter()
ConcertAttendee2.add(3)
ConcertAttendee2.add(3)
ConcertAttendee2.undo()
print("Total concert attendees: " + str(ConcertAttendee2.get_total() ))
```

Comment: You **don't** get `NameError` for a reference to `self` there. `self` *is* defined. `_last` is undefined because it's not a parameter, whereas `_new` and `self._new` are both defined, as a parameter and attribute respectively.

Comment: Show the exact code causing the error and the complete stack trace. Unable to reproduce the first error based on information provided

Comment: Thank you, that is making more sense now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe pointed, in your `undo` method, you do not have a parameter named `_last`, therefore you get an error for `self._tot -= _last`.

You might get the error `self._tot += _new with self._tot += self._new`, if you delete `self` from function argument.

Also, a python convention: Use underscore for class attributes not for parameters. The code below is better in terms of naming conventions.

```
class PremiumCounter:   

    def __init__(self, tot = 0):
        self._tot = tot        
        self._new = 0
        #self._last = 0

    def add(self, new = 1):
        self._tot += new
        self._last = new

    def undo(self):
        self._tot -= self._last       

    def get_total(self):
        return self._tot

    def clear_counter(self):
        self._tot = 0
```

Comment: Next level of better naming: don't use abbreviations if you don't need to. `total` would be a better name than `tot`. The program won't run faster if you use shorter names but loses readability (fun fact: "tot" means "dead" in german language).

Comment: That is a very helpful explanation thank you. It looks like I needed to step back from this code and take a broader look at how it was working